# Ant-Design Table > How can I disable pagination and show all records

Tags: antd

My questions are Ant-Design Table > How can I disable pagination and show all records... Currently, I can configure the pagination component but I don't know how to disable it.
Thanks

Answer (score 96):

Just found it: Simply set pagination to false as below:

```
return (
    <Table 
        rowKey="id" 
        columns={columns} 
        dataSource={data} 
        pagination={false} 
    />
);
```

Comment: how to add my own custom component of pagination to antd Table after disabling the pagination

Comment: This limits the rows to 10.

Comment: @wallurjs That's not true. At least not in the latest version of antd.